# Explain this order of execution of setTimeout and catch handlers

Tags: javascript, settimeout, es6-promise, event-loop

I have this doubt regarding order of execution of Timer functions , microtasks and event listeners :

```
let promise = Promise.reject("Err@!");

setTimeout(() => {
        promise.catch(er => console.log(er, "Caught !"));         // (1)
});

window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => console.log("Unhandled Rejection !", event.reason));  //  (2)

// Output 
// >> Unhandled Rejection ! Err@!
// >> Err@! Caught !
```

In this, the rejected promise gets caught by `Unhandled Rejection` event before being caught by `.catch()` inside `setTimeout`, the reason for that is:

> An "unhandled rejection" occurs when a promise error is not handled at
> the end of the microtask queue (https://javascript.info/microtask-queue#unhandled-rejection)

Now Considering another case :

```
let promise = Promise.reject("Err@!");

setTimeout(() => {       // (1)  ,gets called first

    setTimeout(function () {  // (3) , gets called at last , (after (2))
        promise.catch(er => console.log("caught ", er  ))
    })

});

setTimeout(function () {      // (2) , gets called after (1)
    window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => console.log("Unhandled Rejection !", event.reason));
})

// Output 
//>>  caught  Err@!
```

In this, the promise gets caught by `catch` handler in nested `setTimeout`, even when in second `setTimeout`, the microtask queue is empty and the rejected promise is still not handled by window event listener...

Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the promise rejects (without being handled), the *unhandledrejection* handler was not attached yet, thus it does not handle the case. You can attach `.catch` and `.then` handlers whenever you want, and if the Promise already resolved/rejected, they will fire immeadiately (in a microtask).

```
 // first example
 1) synchronous execution
  - promise rejected
  - timeout set 
  - unhandledrejection event handler attached
 2) microtasks
  - promise rejects
 3) macrotask
  - timeout triggers
    -> .catch handler gets attached
 4) microtasks
   .catch gets executed

 // second example
 1) synchronous execution
 - timers get attached
 - promise rejects
 2) microtasks
 - promise rejected
 3) macrotasks
 - timer 1 done
   - timer 3 started
 - timer 2 done 
    - unhandledrejection handler added
```